# Function not able to be sync between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been trying to use the executor service. However, I am failing to see the sync output.
Like one thread should hold the lock, execute the loop and then the next thread.

Can someone point what I am doing wrong?

```
    public class Arc implements Runnable {
    public synchronized void run() {
        int  c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(c++ + " ");
        }

    }
}


class ArcTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Arc arc = new Arc();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        executorService.execute(new Arc());
        executorService.execute(new Arc());
        executorService.shutdown();

    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 8 9 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: A `synchronized` method will acquire the lock on the instance. You have two separate instances of `Arc`, so the two threads acquire locks on two separate objects.

Comment: These are different objects, so the lock is different and each thread acquires its own (different) lock.  You'll need to lock something in common if you want them to work sequentially.

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting, just a single object of arc would do the trick ?

Comment: Got it. :-D, please do write in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword synchronizes access per object. Since you've created two `Arc` instances, both instances can execute the method at the same time. There are multiple solutions possible to synchronize execution of the loop within the `run` methods of your `Arc` instances:

- Only use a single instance of `Arc`. This might or might not be possible given your application.
- Enqueue runnable tasks instead of using an async executor. This makes most sense if your tasks should run on another thread, but not async.
- Use a `synchronized (LOCK_OBJ) {...code...}` block within the `run` method that synchronizes on some lock object that will be the same for both instances of `Arc` (i.e. `private static final Object LOCK_OBJ = new Object();`)

Which decision is best really depends on your application, but at least this gives you some reasonable options.